# Securing SQL Connection string in ASP.NET Core Windows authentication application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, connection-string

Is there a way to secure the connection string or any user secret for ASP.NET Core application using Windows authentication?

Comment: Windows authentication is secure.  It uses a Windows User Password and whenever data is sent between two windows machines the data is encrypted including a connection string.

Comment: do you wanna know if there is a way to encrypt your appsettings file ?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you're using Windows Authentication, the connection string shouldn't need to contain sensitive data - if it does, you likely have a mistake in it. Your connection string should contain the absolute minimum amount of information required to connect to your database (e.g. server name, authentication type) - no more.

By definition, if you're using Always Encrypted, you don't need to include any user secret in your connection string in order to log on - so don't include it.

Any other user secrets not related to connecting to the database can be stored via another mechanism, such as SQL Server's [Always Encrypted mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).